# The correct use of a Sql CASE statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, case

i have the below query which i am using to update the gender column, if its set at Male, then update as M, for Female, update to F

The statement runs fine the first time round.

```
UPDATE [People].[People]
SET GENDER = CASE WHEN GENDER = 'Male' THEN 'M' 
WHEN GENDER = 'Female' THEN 'F'  END WHERE Id=40
```

my issue is, if the gender is already 'M' then when the statement is run again, 'M' is set to NULL

I could do the below, but it seems a bit of a fudge

```
UPDATE [People].[People]
SET GENDER = CASE WHEN GENDER = 'Male' THEN 'M' 
WHEN GENDER = 'Female' THEN 'F' 
    WHEN GENDER = 'M' THEN 'M'
WHEN GENDER = 'F' THEN 'F'
END WHERE Id=40
```

Can anyone advise ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add another condition to the WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE [People].[People]
SET GENDER = CASE WHEN GENDER = 'Male' THEN 'M' 
WHEN GENDER = 'Female' THEN 'F'  END 
WHERE Id=40 
AND NOT GENDER IN ('M', 'F')
```

This will avoid updating rows again.

Answer (score 4):

Default to the existing value;

```
SET GENDER = CASE 
  WHEN GENDER = 'Male' THEN 'M' 
  WHEN GENDER = 'Female' THEN 'F'   
  ELSE GENDER
END WHERE Id=40
```

Or even

```
SET GENDER = LEFT(GENDER, 1)
```

Comment: For sure.  If you don't want to edit all rows, you could also add a WHERE clause to your Update to only touch rows that are 'Male' or 'Female' (or not 'M' or 'F'), for the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `IN`

```
UPDATE [People].[People]
SET GENDER = CASE WHEN GENDER in ('Male','M') THEN 'M' 
WHEN GENDER in ('Female','F')  THEN 'F'  END WHERE Id=40
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to update the column when it's either `'Male'` or `'Female'`, stipulate that as an additional criterion to your statement. And since it appears that you want to leave just the first character, you could use LEFT() or SUBSTRING() to extract it instead of your CASE expression.

So, here you go:

```
UPDATE [People].[People]
SET GENDER = LEFT(GENDER, 1)
WHERE Id = 40
AND GENDER IN ('Male', 'Female')
;
```